# Access the html content of directive in parent controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an overlay and I set its position manually by accessing the html content and getting the height, width etc.

Now, I have converted the overlay to a directive. But I cant access the html content of the directive itself to update the position.

What have I tried: I tried using replace:true in the directive. But when I try to access the div - I still get the directive element rather than the directive html content.
Eg: 
My Directive:

```
<my-dir somevalue='something'>
</my-dir>
```

Directive HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
<span>{{somevalue}}</span>
</div>
```

Now when I try to access the directive element, I want to access the class 'overlay'

Comment: can you create a sample repo to show your case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your directive template, you should probably be referring to `somevalue`, not `something`, since presumably `somevalue` is what's being set on the directive's scope.

Then to access the `.overlay` child element, in your directive's `link` function you can use the `querySelector` method on the directive's native DOM element, like so:

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
  var overlayElement = el[0].querySelector('.overlay');
}
```

The `el` that's passed into the `link` function is the jqLite-wrapped directive element, so `el[0]` gets you the native DOM element.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikejacobson/bmokpc9k/1/) demonstrating this approach.

Comment: Thanks.. I used this approach.